# git command to get complete details of each branch in repository

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, reporting

I am currently making a tool where I need to fetch details:

- author
- commit date
- change
- commit message

I used something like this

```
git log --pretty=format:'%C(yellow)%h|%Cred%ad|%Cblue%an|%Cgreen%d %Creset%s' --date=short | column -ts'|' | less -r
```

Now here's a catch I want this for every branch on the repository, I tried git checkout and executed the above command. But the results which I'm observing is the same as that of master.

can anyone suggest me what to do?
I have a full clone of the repository.

PS: no APIs as this is not bitbucket or GitHub.

Comment: What do you mean by "the results is the same as that of master"? I got different results for every branch I've checkouted in my repository...

Comment: This question makes me think that you don't understand how git log works... You are seeing _every commit_, not just master.

Comment: Any given commit can be on many branches simultaneously. If your repository has only one root commit (many if not most do), that commit is on *every* branch. Some commits will often be only on one branch, until they get merged into `master` or wherever; after that they will be on more than one branch. The set of branches containing any given commit *changes* over time!

Comment: Thank you everyone for suggestion. I realized my lack of understanding here.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to log every single commit from the repository, you need the `--all` option.

`git log --all`

logs all commits in all branches. So, just alter your git log command and you should be all set.